# Как использовать vue-cli с перезагрузкой страницы

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-cli

Как использовать vue-cli ( компонентный подход ) как традиционный сайт ( не spa ), чтобы была перезагрузка при переходе на другую страницу ?

Comment: Попробуйте вот отсюда почитать: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/issues/1639 и доку где-то отсюда Build the app in multi-page mode

Comment: Благодарю, иду читать!